# The truth or truth?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, writing, learning

"We always like boys who speak the truth"

This sentence is written in my grammar book. I don't understand how is it correct. As far as I was told, articles are omitted before abstract noun unless it is used in particular sense or qualified by an adjective, adjectival clause or phrase.

Answer (score 2):

The example from the grammar book is correct and breaks no rules of the English language.

'Truth' can be:

1. An abstract noun equal in meaning to 'veracity', 'honesty'

*What we live by in our community is truth and justice.*

2. A regular noun equal to 'fact'

*You need to learn these scientific truths.*

3. A noun equal in meaning to 'reality', 'what happened'

*I will tell you the truth (about sth).*

See: https://www.lexico.com/definition/truth

More detailed take on the issue here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truth

Answer (score 1):

Standard usage and common practice show that this is correct, despite what you may have been taught from a grammarian standpoint. Most English native speakers don't know the grammar of their own language, as it is not usually taught in schools so thoroughly as in other countries.

"The truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth"is a standard phrase for example in court rooms, and I for one am not about to tell the judge that something is not quite right.

Comment: *"Most English native speakers don't know the grammar of their own language"* - +1!

Comment: For example, I had no idea what verb tenses were until I went to secondary school and began to study foreign  languages.

Comment: I agree. Usually teaching a foreign language formally, involves having to be explicit about the structures of English for the first time, which hitherto most have simply absorbed in an ad-hoc fashion.